# Accessing static members inside property class

Tags: c++, templates, template-argument-deduction, type-deduction

It is very difficult for me to formulate what I need - sorry - so please make some changes to the question if you think it might make it better understandable for others.

I will create a short example of what I would like to do:

I have a class that has a static function and an object member:

```
class A
{
public:
    Member x;

    static std::string getName()
    {
        return "Name of A";
    }
};
```

This is the definition of Member:

```
class Member
{
public:
    void printSomething()
    {
        cout<<"I am a member of "<<ClassWhereIAmAMember::getName()<<endl; //what can I use instead of ClassWhereIAmAMember??
    }
};
```

My final result should be that I can use `Member` like this:

```
int main()
{
    A a;
    a.x.printSomething();
}
```

And the final result should be obviously

> I am a member of Name of A

I know I could change `Member` to a template class and declaring it in `A` like `Member<A> x` but I would like to keep this as simple and as clean as possible. And in my opininion the compiler should be able to deduce it from the context.

Unfortunately I can't think of any method/paradigm how to accomplish this. Is there a way?

Comment: You could change `Member` to store a function pointer/function object to the function you want `printSomething` to call.

Comment: @NathanOliver My main goal to keep it as simple as possible for the user of `Member`. I think with your solution they still have to provide some additional information in the declaration, right?

Comment: @Mona04_ Yes that could be a way! Still, I think, actually the compiler should be able to aute deduce it using some "template magic"

Comment: C++ does not have reflection, so you need to provide some mechanism to inform `Member` which type you want to call the static member function on.  What actual problem are you trying to solve? There might be a different way to do it.

Comment: _And in my opininion the compiler should be able to deduce it from the context._ Why should it be able to do that? An instance of `Member` could exist in many different places at the same time. What should happen if it was a member of two (or more) different classes? What should happen if it's not a member of a class at all but is used as a local variable in a function? What if it's a temporary? What if it's wrapped in a smart pointer?

Comment: @Kyle That's a good point and I totally agree! Still i could immagine that there is some "template magic" or maybe macros which makes it possible to accomplish it

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your comments, especially the one about reflection. I did some research and came up with the following solution. It is not perfect since it uses macros, but it does exactly what I needed. So if you know a solution without macros please post an answer.

My solution is to define `Member` as a macro:

```
#define Member struct Member_ \
{ \
    void printSomething() \
    { \
        std::string name = getName();  \
        cout<<"I am a member of "<<name<<endl; \
    } \
}
```

This way i can use it like

```
int main()
{
    A a;
    a.x.printSomething();
}
```